# What does the notation $\{ 1,2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

What does the notation $\{ 1,2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ mean?  I have to build a bijection
  $\{ 1,2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}  \to \{ 3,4 \}^{\mathbb{P}} $ ($\mathbb{P}$   denotes the set of odd numbers)   but have  no idea what is the set $\{ 1,2 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally $X^Y$ means all functions from $Y$ to $X$. In this case $\{1,2\}^{\mathbb N}$ means all sequences with values 1 or 2.

Comment: sequences  or functions?

Comment: @Leox whatever you prefer. There is no essential difference between a sequence with indexset $\mathbb N$ and a function with domain $\mathbb N$. Personally I would go for functions.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Then  what sequence corresponds to a  function  of  $\{ 3,4 \}^{\mathbb{P}}$?

Comment: @Leox Exactly the fact that this question arises is on its own a good reason to do it with functions in this context. In the answer above $\mathbb P$ is not mentioned, so there was no bothering about it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A^B$ is the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$.

In the case when $B$ is the natural numbers, that means $A^\mathbb N$ is the set of all infinite sequences of elements of $A$.